# Android Studio 1.1 won't run project

Tags: android-studio

Suddenly my Android Studio project can't run anymore. Either from the "play" button or Run/Run 'app'. When I click them nothing happens. No errors, nothing.

This started happening after I installed the 1.2 Android Studio update, but then downgraded to 1.1 again and the problem still exists.

I can't remember doing any other changes other than installing the AS 1.2 update.

How can I fix this? Is there any other way to run a project?

Comment: Had the same issue. Funny thing: after I read this question and switched back to Android Studio to locate the run configuration the play button was active. Of course, I have no idea what's going on, maybe anybody can shed some light?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Resolved by deleting the existing run configuration and created a new one with the same settings. I can only guess the run configuration was somewhow corrupted by the Android Studio update.

Answer (score 2):

Just restarting Android Studio worked for me.

Comment: In my case I started off by loading a test which never did work. Reload android studio and we are off to the races.

Answer (score 0):

Even i was facing the same issue, after digging into AndroidStuido i tried going to SDK Manager and installed the suggested the install packages (shows in install button with 'Install(1) Package') ..after installing that now i am able to run my app...

i think some SDK was not uptodate or might not installed properly..so try this!

Answer (score 0):

No answer worked for me. So I tried to Invalidate and Restart and it worked well.
Just go to File -> Invalidate caches/Restart... Click Invalidate and Restart button.

Answer (score 0):

In my case restarting the device worked.